# use of typeid to make a comparison between derived classes

Tags: c++, types

I have a vector of pointers to derived objects insert by the user (so I guess the correct term is "known only in runtime)::

```
vector<Person *> vect;
```

The derived classes are Male and Female.
I want to make an iteration on the vector to select only the Female objects and call the copyconstructor of that.
I thought 3 solutions:

1. To use a flag;
2. To use typeid
3. To insert a calling to the copy constructor in the default constructor of Female so every time the user creates one, automatically create the twin.

I don't like the first option in the case of many kind of derived classes.
I don't like the third option too because would cause a problem of relationship (the World knows every Female but the Female can't know the World).
So I should use the second option:
example

```
typeid(vect.at(i))==typeid(Female)
```

Is this expression correct?
Is there another way to outline the problem?

Comment: It's hard to give advice based on an example like this one. For this case I would say to simply use a flag, because gender is a characteristic of a person. Inheritance sounds like a silly way to model that.

Comment: `typeid(vect.at(i))==typeid(Female)` is not going to work

Comment: i agree with @R.MartinhoFernandes, but if you do still try polymorphism than a dynamic cast might be useful here.

Comment: @L7ColWinters: dynamic cast. Why? thank you

Comment: read, http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having `Male` and `Female` inherit from `Person` sounds like a really strange design, but here we go:

```
vector<Person*> vect;
vector<Female*> females;
for (vector<Person*>::const_iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it)
{
    if (Female* p = dynamic_cast<Female*>(*it))
    {
        females.push_back(p);   // copy the pointer
    }
}
```

If you really want to perform a copy of the female, which again sounds strange, replace the last line with:

```
        females.push_back(new Female(*p));   // copy the pointee
```

Comment: I didn't remember to write it but Person is an abstract class. Your code it's good but I have to change the (new Female(*p)) with a call to a clone function, i guess

Comment: Why? At the point of the `push_back`, you already *know* that you have a `Female` at hand. Or does `Female` have further subclasses? *Only then* would calling a polymorphic clone function make sense.

Comment: What if "Female" has functions that are unavailable to "Male"? Does it still not make sense to have "Male" and "Female" as subclasses of "Person"? `Female::breastFeed` etc. Not trying to correct you, I'm genuinly curios if it is bad design.

Answer (score 3):

```
typeid(vect.at(i))==typeid(Female)
```

is wrong if `vect` contains pointers. You mean

```
typeid(*vect.at(i)) == typeid(Female))
```

Whether `typeid` or a simple flag should be used depends on the architecture of your program, specifically on whether you really need polymorphism. I don't really understand your third option.

Comment: the third option maybe doesn't work but consists to insert a clone function in the costructor of Female to call the owner copy constructor. Anyway, i prefer typeid or dynamic cast. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't model gender with inheritance, but rather just use an enumerated type in `Person`. Then you can use `transform` or `remove_copy_if` or similar to find the female indicated objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dynamic_cast to do this.
For example this makes fp point to a female in the case where pp holds a Female object, and null otherwise:

```
Person *pp;
Female *fp;
// ... 
fp = dynamic_cast<Female *> (pp);
if (fp)
   fp->DoFemaleThing();
else
   cout << "Cast from Person to Female pointer failed";
```